# Coq forward reasoning: apply with multiple hypotheses

Tags: coq, ltac

I have two hypothesis, and I would like to use forward reasoning to apply a theorem that uses both of them.

My specific I have the hypothes

```
H0 : a + b = c + d
H1 : e + f = g + h
```

and I want to apply the theorem from the standard library:

```
f_equal2_mult
     : forall x1 y1 x2 y2 : nat, x1 = y1 -> x2 = y2 -> x1 * x2 = y1 * y2
```

Now I know I could manually give the values for x1, y1, x2, y2, but I would like Coq to automatically determine those values when it unified with `H0` and `H1`.  I have figured out that I can get it to work like so:

```
eapply f_equal2_mult in H0; try exact H1.
```

But this feels like a hack, with the broken symmetry and the `try`.  I really would like to be able to say `apply f_equals2_mult in H0, H1` or something similarly clear.  Is there a way like this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `pose proof` to introduce the lemma in the context, and [`specialize`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.specialize) to apply it to other hypotheses.

```
Lemma f (a b c d : nat) : a = b -> c = d -> False.
intros H1 H2.
pose proof f_equal2_mult as pp.
specialize pp with (1 := H1).
specialize pp with (1 := H2).

(* or *)
specialize pp with (1 := H1) (2 := H2).
```

Comment: Or `specialize (f_equal2_mult _ _ _ _ H1 H2).`, or `pose proof (f_equal2_mult _ _ _ _ H1 H2).`

Comment: What about the case where it is an iff relation (<->)?  e.g. apply Nat.mul_cancel_r to `H1: n<>0` and `H2: a*n=b*n` ?

Comment: If you have `H : P <-> Q` in the context, you can use `apply proj1 in H` to convert it to `H : P -> Q`.

Comment: Combining proj1 with post proof, I was able to get the one-liner `pose proof (proj1 (Nat.mul_cancel_r _ _ _ H1)) H2` for the bidirectional case.